# Can I apply filter to data result of useStaticQuery in Gatsby.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am a beginner in Gatsby.js, I am developing a page with a dropdown of 12 months. Once user select the month, I will pass the value into a component, which will display different set of result based on month selected.

There is a graphql query to retrieve data by using useStaticQuery in my component.

I understand the useStaticQuery cannot accept any variable, so is it possible to filter the returned data and create another data set based on the month inputted? Or should I just create 12 components and display the correspondning one based on month selected?

(Actually I tried to loop the data and return a single aggregate value successfully, but I not sure if it is possible to return a subset of data result

```
data.allData.edges.forEach(edge => {
    if(edge.node.month==inputMonth)
        total=total+edge.node.amount
})
outValue= total
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use a [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) loop. In your case:

```
let matchedMonth = data.allData.edges.find(edge => edge.node.month === inputMonth)
```

Basically, you are looping through `allData` (all months) to find which one is exactly equal to `inputMonth`. Since you are saving it in `matchedMonth` you can play whatever you want (passing to a component, etc).

Comment: Not exactly what I need but your answer reminds me that the data result is actually just array, so I can manipulate it by javascript array method to get whatever I want, thanks